# Importing posts content from csv

Tags: phpmyadmin

I want to export some specific posts from my database (csv or sql) and then replace content to these and import them back without changing the id number of the posts.I s this possible to do it and if it is, how?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wp all export to export posts, change content. Them import them back with wp all import. Use update existing post option and chose to unique ID to be post title and to update only content field.. So it will find post with same title, it won't change it and just update content.

Comment: I tried to export and import with the above plugins but my problem seems to be more complicated. The posts I want to change is translations from wpml and many posts have the same name (long story). When I tried to import the secondary language posts, the updates of the content applied to the posts of main language. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Contact wpml if they any suggestions. I know I had same problem with polylang and they have some plugin for multilanguage import.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way you can export and importing post content is by using these two plugins:

1. [Export WordPress data to XML/CSV](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-export/)
2. [Import any XML or CSV File to WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-import/)

You can use the first plugin to export your desired posts from the database. Then use the second plugin to import them back.